# Linux Log Trace Watcher

Tags: linux, logging, trace

I'm looking for a linux daemon which tails a log file and examine each new coming line with set of patterns (such as REGEX). In case of pattern matching there be a notifier script which in turn sends notifications to other programs.

-- afshin

Comment: What does this have to do with software development?

Comment: Actually I need to add automatic workflows to an existing software application which does not aware of my external workflow engine! In first step I need to generate notifications which trig by user interactions. The only way that I have is the software application log traces :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) with something like this:

```
<Input in>
    Module  im_file
    File    "/var/log/custom_app.log"
    Exec    if $raw_event =~ /regexpattern/ exec_async('/path/to/notification_script.sh');
</Input>

<Output out>
    Module  om_null
</Output>

<Route 1>
       Path in => out
</Route>
```

Probably there are a dozen other ways to solve this (rsyslog, syslog-ng come to mind).